# Is there a way to fix the truncated names in the app drawer?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

How do I fix the annoying truncation of program names in the Ubuntu 22.04 app drawer?[image: screenshot showing app drawer with truncated names highlighted with arrow]

Answer (score 2):

You can consider installing `Main Menu` from Ubuntu Software for 22.04 (ubuntu-jammy-universe (deb).

[image]

This app will allow you to manage menus in GNOME renaming them as required to make them more meaningful to you.

As an example, I used this tool to change the rather lengthy named `Money Manager Ex` application to simply `MMEX` as it is otherwise known.

[image]

Comment: so there's no way to change the size, kerning, or wrap settings?